# ValueError: unknown is not supported on multiclass dependent variable

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to fit a vector in sklearn, but I'm receiving this error:

> ValueError: unknown is not supported
>   This is my code:

```
    X = df_features.values
    X = X.reshape((len(X),len(df_features.columns)))
    Y = df_train['action'].values
    Y = Y.reshape((len(Y),))

pipeline = Pipeline([
 ('clf', RandomForestClassifier())
])

parameters = {
    'clf__max_depth': [5,7,9],
    'clf__max_features': [3,4,5],
    'clf__min_samples_leaf': [3,4,5,6,7],
    'clf__bootstrap': [True]
}

score_func = make_scorer(metrics.f1_score,average='weighted')

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, n_jobs=3,
  verbose=1, scoring=score_func)

grid_search.fit(X, Y)
```

This is Y sample data:

> ['NOTHING', 'NOTHING', 'SELL', 'SELL', 'NOTHING',
>          'NOTHING', 'NOTHING']

How can I fix this?
Thanks

Comment: You have to use a binarizer to binarize the y to 0s and 1s. If you upload your data I can provide an example

Comment: @sera. Its not required. The scikit-learn estimators automatically handle the conversion of class labels.

Comment: What is the type of `Y`. Show `type(Y)`. Try  `Y = Y.astype('str')` before fitting.

Comment: @VivekKumar the result of astype is this: dtype='|S21')

Comment: Are the library versions identical on your local and EC2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the type and size of x and y. Also, do you have enough samples for the desired max_depth and min_samples_leaf ?

The following example seems to work fine. I used the iris data and leave one out cross validation just as an example.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import fbeta_score, make_scorer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris 
import numpy as np
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut


loo= LeaveOneOut()
data = load_iris()

x = data.data
x = x[0:14,:]
x.shape

y = ['NOTHING', 'NOTHING', 'SELL', 'SELL', 'NOTHING', 'NOTHING','SELL','SELL','NOTHING','SELL','SELL','NOTHING','NOTHING','NOTHING']
y = np.asarray(y)
y = y.reshape(14,1)
y = y.astype('str')


pipeline = Pipeline( [ ('clf', RandomForestClassifier() )] )

parameters = {'clf__max_depth': [1,2,3], 'clf__max_features': [1,2,3], 'clf__min_samples_leaf': [1,2,3], 'clf__bootstrap': [True] }

score_func = make_scorer(metrics.f1_score,average='weighted')

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, n_jobs=1 , verbose=1, scoring=score_func, cv = loo)

grid_search.fit(x, y)
```

Result

```
Fitting 14 folds for each of 45 candidates, totalling 630 fits
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done 630 out of 630 | elapsed:   33.7s finished
```

Hope this helps

Comment: My code works fine with the same data in my local machine, when I deploy the system to a EC2 machine, it occurs this error

Comment: do you use exactly the same versions in the local and EC2 machine?